# How do I retrieve Hotmail contacts with python

Tags: python, hotmail

How can I retrieve contacts from hotmail with python?

Is there any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotmail: [Windows Live Contacts API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx)

If a python interface doesn't exist you may have to resort to screen scraping.

Answer (score 0):

use octazen, but you have to pay for it

Comment: Since octazen doesn't work anymore for hotmail. Are there any proper Python alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

IIRC Hotmail has POP access, so just use the [poplib](http://docs.python.org/library/poplib.html) library.

Usage is something like this (NOT tested):

```
hotmail = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop3.live.com', 995)
hotmail.user(USERNAME)
hotmail.pass_(PASSWORD)

message_count = len(hotmail.list()[1])

for i in range(message_count):
    for message in hotmail.retr(i+1)[1]
        print message
```

Some connectivity info [here](http://www.neowin.net/news/main/09/03/13/free-windows-live-hotmail-pop3-access-has-gone-worldwide) (might be old).